# JQuery find element in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, unity-game-engine

I am really not great at web stuff, so I am apologizing in advance for a potentially poor explanation of my problem.

Basically, I have a webpage which utilizes the handlebars js templating. Unfortunately, this means that many of my div elements are contained within javascript tags like the following:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
         <div class="row intro">
           ......
         </div>
         <div class="descript">           
           .....
        </div>
</script>
```

My intent is to grab one of these div elements using jquery.find(), but from what I understand, the html within the script tags is not treated as part of the dom...so jquery does not see it as a dom element. I was wondering if there is any other way I could go about this. Some more code is included.

Here is another more explicit explanation in case the one I gave above was a little muddled: I am working on a personal website and would like to embed a project I have been working on in unity3d, but I need to add/remove elements based on whether or not the client has the unity3d web player installed. Normally I would get a particular element with

```
var $missingScreen = jQuery("#unityPlayer").find(".missing");
```

where 'missing' is simply an element inside unityPlayer which displays a link if the client does not have unity3d. I am also using some javascript templating to make my site look pretty and as a result, I have this problem:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div class="row intro">
        <div class="intro-text">Hi, I'm *****</div>
    </div>
    <div class="descript">           
        <p>
            Here's a Project I have been working on in case I am of interest to you:
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div id="unityPlayer">
            <div class="missing">
                <a href="http://unity3d.com/webplayer/" title="Unity Web Player. Install now!">
                <img alt="Unity Web Player. Install now!" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/installation/getunity.png" width="193" height="63" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="footer">&laquo; created with <a href="http://unity3d.com/unity/" title="Go to unity3d.com">Unity</a> &raquo;</p>
</script>
```

Jquery cannot access the missing element. Is there any way to do this? Thanks for any help you can give me and sorry again for my inexperience.

EDIT* some people might want to know: here is how I determine whether or not to show the missing div. Another note; everything works fine if I remove the script tags...it is only when I put html within the script tags that it becomes inaccessible to jquery.

```
jQuery(function() {
                var $missingScreen = jQuery("#unityPlayer").find(".missing");
                $missingScreen.hide();

                u.observeProgress(function (progress) {
                    switch(progress.pluginStatus) {
                        case "missing":
                            $missingScreen.find("a").click(function (e) {
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                e.preventDefault();
                                u.installPlugin();
                                return false;
                            });
                            $missingScreen.show();
                        break;
                        case "installed":
                            $missingScreen.remove();
                        break;
                        case "first":
                        break;
                    }
                });
                u.initPlugin(jQuery("#unityPlayer")[0], "temmp.unity3d");
            });
```

Comment: you can add the whole missing div to a variable and then compare what you want and select that variable to display or not

Comment: I think I do that, but the problem is that statement jquery().find(missing) returns null because the div missing is within those handlebars script tags. I will post the jquery in its entirety

Comment: Can you edit your question and put all the code into a snippet? You should be able to link to handlebars.

Comment: what is the `u` variable? Have you instantiated an instance of the template and attached to the DOM by the time that jquery code is run? If not, jquery won't find anything. You should be able to attach a debugger an step through or do console.log() to see whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
`var $missingScreen = jQuery("#unityPlayer").find(".missing");`
I would try out

```
var $missingScreen = jQuery("#unityPlayer").children(".missing");
```

or

```
var $missingScreen = jQuery("#unityPlayer .missing");
```

Don't forget the space between Player and .missing!

I hope it works.